# How do I implement number increment animation in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I tried to create an animation similar to Twitter's post like counter

[Sample here](https://ibb.co/B4rMrKy)

I want to achieve that same effect/animation. I'm confused about how to implement the animation.

Here's what I have done so far in jQuery:

```js
$(function() {
  var $number = 1;
  $('#test').click(function() {
    var $elem = $(this).find('span');
    var $text = $(this).find('span').text();
    $number = $number + 1;
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(this).find('span').removeClass("static").addClass("up");
    }, 0);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $elem.text($number);
    }, 100);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $elem.removeClass("up").addClass("down");
    }, 100);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $elem.removeClass("down").addClass("static");
    }, 200);
  });
});
```

```css
.up {
  display: inline-flex;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate3d(0, -20px, 0);
  transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.down {
  display: inline-flex;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
}

.static {
  display: inline-flex;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
  transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="test" class="btn btn-sm"><span class="static"> 1</span></button>
```

Comment: You have some error when you click, check your console.

Comment: I saw the error thanks, but why is it giving me that error?

Comment: You have to debug your code

Comment: The code is now working, any help on the animation part?

Comment: The GIF in your question isn't working

Comment: What animation are you trying to do?

Comment: Its working on my end, just checked @NullDev

Comment: @Sfili_81  Twitter like counter animation, you know when you liked a post on twitter, the old number scrolls up and the new count will scroll in.

Comment: I don't know that animation, try to explain because your gif isn't working

Comment: @Sfili_81 I already attached a link to a gif which showcases the animation

Comment: The GIF isn't working. Neither for me, nor for @Sfili_81, as he stated it himself.

Comment: Oh, am trying to upload the image to an image hosting site, I'll provide you guys the link soon, Thanks for your time

Comment: Here's another link to the animation [link](https://ibb.co/B4rMrKy)

Comment: You could find a heart icon on fontawesome then put a before pseudo element on the button and on the animation change to color to red. Is it the heart animation you want?

Comment: @AHaworth Thanks for replying, Am not talking about the heart animation, I am referring to the scrolling number animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were two issues with your code:

1. As mentioned by [@NullDev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7575111/nulldev), you had placed `$text` instead of `$elem` in one of your `setTimeout`s. This was a straightforward typo.
2. The second issue is with the line:

```js
$(this).find('span').removeClass("static").addClass("up");
```

Inside `setTimeout`, the `this` variable is not in the same context as the `this` variable outside the `setTimeout`. To verify this, you can log:

```js
console.log($(this).find('span') === $elem); // should be false
```

To fix this, you simply need to replace:

```js
$(this).find('span').removeClass("static").addClass("up");
```

in your first `setTimeout` with:

```js
$elem.removeClass("static").addClass("up");
```

---

You can find the working code below:

```js
$(function() {
  var $number = 1;
  $('#test').click(function() {
    var $elem = $(this).find('span');
    var $text = $(this).find('span').text();
    $number = $number + 1;
    setTimeout(function() {
      $elem.removeClass("static").addClass("up");
    }, 0);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $elem.text($number);
    }, 100);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $elem.removeClass("up").addClass("down");
    }, 100);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $elem.removeClass("down").addClass("static");
    }, 200);
  });
});
```

```css
.up {
  display: inline-flex;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate3d(0, -20px, 0);
  transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.down {
  display: inline-flex;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
}

.static {
  display: inline-flex;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
  transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="test" class="btn btn-sm"><span class="static"> 1</span></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code throws an exception:

> Uncaught TypeError: $text.removeClass is not a function

You define `$text` as

```js
var $text = $(this).find('span').text();
```

Thus, it is a normal String which is why `$text.removeClass()` won't work. 
You probably meant to write

```js
$elem.removeClass(...)
```

Comment: I have debugged the code and its now working, but what about the animation part?